# Compatibility issue between VS2010, Pex, and SlimDX

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, compatibility, slimdx, pex

I have downloaded June bits of Pex and June bits of SlimDX SDK.  Installed them on my RTM VS2010 Premium.
Pex explorations do not work.  Reverting to Feb 2010 bits of SlimDX seem to cure the problem.

I've asked the same question on Microsoft Forums and SlimDX forums, and neither party wants to own this.  How can I even begin to troubleshoot this?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/pex/thread/c347ddbf-4c08-4612-a127-c92e87f2572d

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=577415

Comment: You should file a bug on the SlimDX bug tracker; I don't recall seeing your GDNet thread until now and I only found this via a random Google Alert. 

However, I should warn you this doesn't sound like anything that's at all related to SlimDX. The only things I can think of offhand are that (a) C++/CLI assemblies in the GAC render PEX unusable for some reason and (b) the SlimDX installer installs some other file that's otherwise incompatible with PEX (mainly we install the DX redists and the C++ runtimes).

Can you get any kind of debug log out of PEX?

Comment: Would it be fair to say that VC10 Runtime stays when you uninstall SlimDX?

Comment: Turning on Diagnostic messages in Pex does not do anything more than the default settings in this case.  They haven't published symbols for Pex either.

Comment: Initially reporting on XP SP3 32-bit, now observing on Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peli has answered this question on the Pex forum.  It worked for me.  See the link above.